# Xamarin Scrollview scrollbar not visible

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, scrollview, scrollbar

Xamarin.Forms on Android. I have scrollView with stack inside. Scroll works, but scrollBar not visible. I've tried to write custom renders but it didn't help. 
My code: https://github.com/FeduniakVitalii/ScrollView

```
var contentAndWebViewLayout = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand};
            contentAndWebViewLayout.Children.Add(contentLayout);
            contentAndWebViewLayout.Children.Add(webView);

            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView()
            {
                Content = contentAndWebViewLayout,
                IsEnabled = true,
                IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled = true,
                IsClippedToBounds = true,
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };

            var converter = new HtmlLabelConverter();

            var layout = new RelativeLayout()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            layout.Children.Add(scrollView,
            xConstraint: Constraint.Constant(0),
                    yConstraint: Constraint.Constant(0),
                    widthConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
                    heightConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));

            this.Content = layout;
```

Comment: Do you have enough content to scroll?

Comment: Yes, but ContentHeight we will now after render webview.

Comment: According to your description, I can not reproduce your issue, so can you provide one sample on github, so I can download your sample to test.

Comment: https://github.com/FeduniakVitalii/ScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to downgrade Xamarin.Forms version to 3.4, problem solved !

Comment: sadly that won't be a solution for ever. It seems that the bug has been fixed several versions ago and then bugfix was reverted. So it seems, Bug is back (at least) in 4.7. Can anyone confirm?